# Transparency & runtime themes

Tags: delphi, themes, transparency, c++builder-xe2

When runtime themes are disabled for whole project, transparent images are drawn with black background. Is it possible to draw transparent image on button when runtime themes are disabled? The button I am using is from TMS Component Pack, its class name is `TAdvToolButton`. I need to have themes disabled because I want to fully control how application looks like. This is important request.
Please try to explain the connection between transparency & themes because I don't see it. I think these are two different things.

Comment: Disabling runtime themes doesn't stop the system from drawing transparently. So clearly it's down to the code and components you use. I'd contact the vendor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm with you but Menus or Toolbars e.g. are unuseable with Imaglists using PNG's and disabled runtime themes.

Comment: @bummi I don't know where PNGs come into it. My menus and toolbars use 32bpp icons in imagelists and display fine with runtime themes disabled.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan mine, with Delphi XE, cd32Bit draw black background

Comment: @bummi Sounds like you need to start using proper icons and standard image lists. Don't use PNG. It's not native. Use 32bpp icon resources.

Comment: I use Thany's `TPngImageList` and it works fine for displaying transparent PNG images, except in a few isolated cases (Toolbars and ListViews under Win9x), in which case I copy the PNGs at runtime to transparent bitmaps and put them into a masked TImageList where needed.